# Nexus Repository manager OSS 3 proxy and save

Tags: repository, nexus

I need following: when client request package from Nexus proxy repository - the package will be downloaded from Intenet to Nexus, but not delivered to client.
Is it possible?

Comment: When you say client do you mean a person or a tool?  I'm pretty confident you can do this using curl however I suspect you may mean a person.  If you mean a tool is there a specific tool you have in mind or do you just need a way to have this done?

Comment: I mean a person. He will run npm install.. and package will be cached in proxy repository, but not delivered to man.

Comment: I do not believe you can do this with NXRM.  You may be able to do what you need using IQ or Firewall products in conjunction but not 100% sure.